# How to calculate total RSS of all thread stacks under Linux?

Tags: linux-kernel, pthreads

I have a heavily multi-threaded application under Linux consuming lots of memory and I am trying to categorize its RSS. I found particularly challenging to estimate total RSS of all thread stacks in program. I had following ideas:

**Idea 1**: look into `/proc/<pid>/smaps` and consider mappings for stacks; there is an information regarding resident size of each mapping but only the main thread mapping is annotated like [stack]; the rest of them is indistinguishable from regular 8 MiB mappings (with default stack size). Also reading `/proc/<pid>/smaps` is pretty expensive as it produces contention on kernel innternal VMA data structures.

**Idea 2**: look into `/proc/<tid>/status`; there is `VmStk` section which should describe stack resident size, but it always shows stack size of a main thread. It looks pretty clear why: beacuse main thread is the only one for which kernel allocates stack by itself, while the rest of threads gets stack from pthreads code which allocates it as a regular memory mapping.

**Idea 3**: traverse threads from user-space using some stuff from pthreads, retrieve stack mapping address and stack size for each thread and then find out how many pages are resident using `mincore(2)`. As a possible optimization, we may skip calling mincore for sleeping threads using the cached value for them. Unfortunately, I did not find any suitable way to iterate over `pthread_t` structures. Note that part of the threads comes from the libraries which I am not able to control, so maintaining any kind of thread registry by registering threads on startup is not possible.

**Idea 4**: use `ptrace(2)` to retrieve thread registers, retrive stack pointers from them, then proceed with **Idea 1**. This way looks excessively hard and intrusive.

Can anybody provide me more or less intended way to do so? Being non-portable is OK.

---

Two more ideas I got after some extra research:

**Idea 5**: from `man 5 proc` on `/proc/<pid>/maps`:

```
              There are additional helpful pseudo-paths:

                   [stack]
                          The initial process's (also known as the main thread's) stack.

                   [stack:<tid>] (since Linux 3.4)
                          A thread's stack (where the <tid> is a thread ID).  It corresponds to the /proc/[pid]/task/[tid]/ path.
```

It looks intriguing, but it seems that this logic has been reverted as it was implemented ineffiiently: https://lore.kernel.org/patchwork/patch/716239/. Man page seems obsolete (at least on my Ubuntu Disco 19.04).

**Idea 6**: This one may actually work. There is an `/proc/<tid>/syscall` file which may expose thread stack register for a blocked thread. Considering the fact that most of my threads are sleeping on I/O, this allows me to track their rsp value, which I may project onto `/proc/<pid>/maps` to find the correspondence between thread and its stack mapping. After that I may implement **Idea 3**.

Comment: `beacuse main thread is the only one for which kernel allocates stack by itself, while the rest of threads gets stack from pthreads` so byte your problem from the other side - get pthreds to tell you stack of thread. `pthread_attr_getstacksize`

Comment: @KamilCuk
That's exactly what I tried in "idea 3", but I did not find any suitable API in pthreads to traverse all the threads. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Puff, I guess you could mask `pthread_start` with `LD_PRELOAD` and accumulate thread ids in some array.

Comment: Good idea; quite technical but should work. I'll keep that as a backup plan, thx!